# Conditional count in one column based on values in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set with following variables. Sample is as shown below.

```
Sr  Gender  Score   Answer
1   F   11  A
2   M   7   A
3   F   2   B
4   F   1   
5   F   -1  A
6   F   3   D
7   F   11  B
8   M   9   C
9   M   12  A
10  M   15  A
11  M   -6  
12      7   A
13  F   -6  A
```

I want to count

FOR GENDER == F and SCORE between 0-10, how much fraction of ANSWERs are A, B, C, D, NA (empty cells).

This exercise I want to run for SCORES from -20 to 100. going in steps of 10.

Similar exercise should give results for GENDER==M.

Expected output is

```
        SCORE   FA  FB  FC  FD  FNA MA  MB  MC  MD  MNA
         -10    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0    1.0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1.0     
          10    0   .33 0   .33 .33 .5  0   .5  0   0   
          20    .5  .5  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
          ....
```

I tried to use summary and table command but I am not able to divert and results by choosing GENDER == 'F' or 'M' specific cells in desired output table. With excel I can do the job but this is huge file with 32000*200 matrices.

Any help or guidance to a proper library function is well appreciated. I am just a beginner to R

Comment: Try `dt <- setDT(df1)[, .N, .(SCORE= cut(Score, breaks = c(-Inf, seq(-20, 100, by = 10)), labels = seq(-20, 100, by = 10)) , Gender, Answer)];dcast(dt, SCORE ~ Gender + Answer, value.var = 'N', drop = FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun what do .N and value.var='N' do? Should it be replaced by F or M?

Comment: It is a default column created based on getting the count (`.N`)

Comment: Or a dplyr way: `library(tidyverse);
d %>% 
  mutate(inter=.bincode(Score,seq(-20,100,10)),
         inter=factor(inter,labels = seq(-20,100,10), levels = seq_along(seq(-20,100,10)))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Gender)) %>% 
  count(inter, Gender, Answer) %>% 
  unite(key,Gender, Answer) %>% 
  spread(key,n,fill=NA, drop=F)`. Note that I used other bins. I feel better with this intervals.

Comment: @akrun I am getting error `could not find function "setDT" `. I think it comes with data.table which is already installed. Any idea?

Comment: have u loaded `library(data.table)`

Comment: @jimbou I apologise if I am asking very basic questions. With your code, I am getting error `Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'd' not found`.

Comment: @praveenpathak d stores the data. You have to replace `d` with the name of your data.frame.